# Does my thread kill itself once I remove the class instance?

Tags: python, multithreading, class

Within a class instance I'm starting a thread and add itself to a list. If I remove the class instance from the list, does the thread stop?

```
SESSIONS = []
session(5)
# Do some other stuff...
SESSIONS.remove(x) # remove created instance

class session:

    def __init__(self, timeValue):
        self.timeValue = timeValue
        threading.Thread(target=self.updateTime).start()
        SESSIONS.append(self)

    def updateTime(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.playtime += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The thread instance is not the thread. The instance is only a handle that your program can use to ask about the thread's state and, to interact with the thread.